# Still have Win10-style volume/brightness sliders after upgrading to Win11

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-11-upgrade

I upgraded my PC from Windows 10 Home to Windows 11 Home, and while everything else about the OS is as expected, there is one thing that hasn't seemed to update: The on-screen sliders for volume and brightness (e.g. that appear when using hardware volume buttons) are still in the rectangular Windows 10 style in the upper left corner, rather than the rounded Windows 11 style in the bottom center of the screen.

Why in the world might this happen? Is there a registry key I can change? Windows is all up to date and I have tried reinstalling graphics drivers (I even tried all graphics drivers compatible with my system to see if any behaved differently).

The volume and brightness sliders still *work*, I'd just prefer if they were thematically unified with the rest of the UI.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Reboot if anything is found.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I did already do that. Didn't help :/

Comment: If you have some Windows 10 leftovers, a [Repair Install](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/) may help. But this is a heavy operation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the device was upgraded to Windows 11 version *2H12*. Many of Windows 11's UI changes, including the updated style of brightness and volume sliders, the tabbed ribbon in Windows Explorer, etc. are only available starting in Windows 11 version *2H22*.